# Reflecting "light beam" in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm quite new to web programming, so apologize me for my ignorance.
I'm starting a simulation about Michelson's experiment for the speed of light: I have a rotating mirrored-octagon, with a beam of light bouncing on it.
The problem is I still can't well understand how to make "js-like" animations on SVG, in this particular case I have no idea of how this "beam" could actually bounce off the octagon(with the same angle of incidence, of course).
Heartfelt thanks in advance,
Greg.

Comment: greg - typically stackoverflow requires you to show the code that you've tried to solve the problem and then people will help you solve the specific issue. Here I'd suggest reading a few tutorials on writing and animating SVG and then coming back with the specific code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started:

Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL

And this simple example:

```html
<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 500 200">

<rect x="75" y="45" width="100" height="5"></rect>
<circle cy="190" cx="25" r="5">
  <animate attributeName="cx" values="25; 125; 225" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" begin="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  <animate attributeName="cy" values="190; 55; 190" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" begin="2s" fill="freeze"/>
</circle>

</svg>
```

Demo:

[image]